# What happened to Lala in To LOVE-Ru Darkness?

Tags: to-love-ru

I'm embarrassed to admit to watching this show. But this question has been bothering me for some time.

Lala is pretty much ***the*** main character in the series. She is the typical "primary" female in this genre of harem Anime.

Lala was the main character for the first two seasons: "To LOVE-Ru" and "Motto To LOVE-Ru".

However, in season 3 (To LOVE-Ru Darkness) Lala suddenly disappears from the stage and is no longer the main character. Instead Momo (Lala's sister) becomes the primary female character.

Why is this? What influenced the author to pull Lala from center stage and replace her with Momo?

Comment: My guess is that it has something to do with why To LOVE-Ru manga stopped serialization.

Comment: Just to back up my comment: http://forums.mangafox.me/threads/98009-possible-reasons-why-they-made-a-rushed-and-the-ending-suck./page2

Comment: I've heard some 2nd/3rd hand info about something to do with the guy's wife complaining that Lala was based off of her. But I'm looking for a more concrete answer with references if possible.

Comment: There is [another person](http://forums.mangafox.me/threads/384897-Where-is-Lala?p=10076978&viewfull=1#post10076978) saying that Haruna, not Lala is based off of his wife. If I'm sure, I'd post as answer already...

Comment: Well, from watching the anime up to reading the manga (currently waiting for Darkness 2nd), I can only say that the author did a really good job on balancing the flags triggered for every heroines in the series. Even though I'm a fan of Momo, I didn't want the series to focus everything on her (just like how it was focusing on Lala on pre-Darkness anime). Fortunately, the continuation from the manga doesn't do that. Before I realized, To LOVE-Ru became one of my top harem anime, and I'll be expecting a lot from To LOVE-Ru! :D

Answer (score 5):

<sup>Note: this answer may contain minor spoilers.</sup>

> Instead Momo (Lala's sister) becomes the primary female character.
>   What influenced the author to pull Lala from center stage and replace her with Momo?

I don't know how far along the anime is, but that's not entirely correct. Momo becomes a more important character than she was in previous TLR instances, but I think that's mainly for amusement / The Harem Plan™. And Lala isn't entirely dead yet. Why she isn't as prominent anymore? I have no real answer to that, but my guess is that her specific story is over and maybe the author just got tired of her. :)

Also, let's look at the name of the anime (and manga): To LOVE-Ru ***Darkness***.
And whose name contains "Darkness" again? Right, Konjiki no Yami, aka *Golden Darkness*.

It becomes apparent pretty fast that she's the new main heroine, as the story revolves around her origin, her purpose, and friends / foes she has out in the universe.

A particular example would be Mea,

> who is an artificial "transforming weapon" just like Yami,

and her mysterious master.

We also finally get to know Yami's mother. It's hard to see where exactly TLR:D is going yet, but it's not your average ecchi fanservice manga / anime anymore.

Comment: Yeah, Yami is definitely more prominent in TLR Darkness Anime. But she's still nothing compared to Momo - who literally trolls Rito for the entire series.

Comment: @Mysticial: The anime must be far removed from the manga if that's the case. The beginning of the manga may focus on her quite a bit, but that changes and she's on par right now with Yami I'd say. Also, Momo doesn't troll Rito. ;)

Comment: Well, the restart really marks a change in direction. There is a plot backing the story now, on which the author can slowly advance on the plot while providing fanservices.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's another story of this movie talk about MoMo, NaNa instead of LaLa. MoMo wanted to make Rito Fall in love with she by her Harem plan because she thinks however married MoMo instead of LaLa, Rito still become the greatest man in the universe. And this story might discover about the mystery girl, Mea. Everyone wanted to find who is Mea's master and her relationship with Yami. About another things, I have no idea. So if there is some thing wrong, please support me because this just my things about this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two reasons:
1)lala makes it hard to develop in relationship because of her child-like nature
2)the other reason is that THE HAREM PLAN of momo is necessary for the development of Yami who is the main focus.

Comment: Do you have evidence for your claims?